# Python Django loop logic: Error says 'int' is not iterable - check my syntax?

Tags: python, django

```
return sum(jobrecord.get_cost() or 0 
    for jobrecord in self.project.jobrecord_set.filter(
        date__lte=date,
        date__gte=self.start_date) or 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a small rewrite

```
query = self.project.jobrecord_set.filter(
        date__lte=date,
        date__gte=self.start_date)
values= ( jobrecord.get_cost() or 0 for jobrecord in query or 0 )
return sum( values )
```

Look closely at the `values= ( jobrecord.get_cost() or 0 for jobrecord in query or 0 )`

What happens when the query is empty?

You're evaluating `jobrecord.get_cost() or 0 for jobrecord in 0`

Answer (score 1):

0 is indeed not iterable. I think you want to drop that last `or 0`.  when the filter query matches no elements, it will return an empty query, and your sum will just be 0, since `sum([])` is zero.

If there's some reason why the query might raise an exception (invalid dates or some such), an or clause wont catch that either.  `[][1] or 0` still raises an exception.